# Shorthand way to check for the next array item with string indexes

Tags: php, arrays

If the array elements are just pushed into the array, then the array elements get consecutive integer indexes, and I can easily check if the next element exists like this.

```
foreach($array as $id => $element) {
   if((isset($array[$id+1]))) {
      // Next array item exists
   } else {
      // Next array element does not exist
   }
}
```

But if they have string indexes, like for example:

```
$array = array(
   'Mark' => 'Totally cool person',
   'Ben'  => 'Kind of a nerd'
);
```

Then can I check for the next element without previously counting the elements and then using a counter inside the loop?

```
$n = count($array);
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $id => $element) {
   if(++$i < $n) {
      // Next array item exists
   } else {
      // Next array item does not exist
   }
}
```

}

Comment: If `isset` is ok (like in your first snippet), then traverse `array_keys($array)` instead of `$array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the keys instead of values. If you want to access the value inside the loop, you can use `$array[$keys[$id]]`.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

foreach($keys as $id => $element) {
   if((isset($keys[$id+1]))) {
      // Next array item exists
   } else {
      // Next array element does not exist
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next items not exists only for last item in array.

May be simple way will remove last item from array, process array without condition and then add last item to array and process it as item without next.